# OOP Python converting list of strings into a list of ShoppingItem objects and assign the list into the self.items_list variable

Tags: python

I have defined a class named `ShoppingItem`.

```
class ShoppingItem:
    def __init__(self, code, description, price=1.0, quantity=1):
        self.code = int(code)
        self.description = str(description)
        self.price = float(price)
        self.quantity = int(quantity)
    
    def __str__(self):
        if self.quantity == 0:
            return ("Code = {}, {} - Out of Stock".format(self.code, self.description))
        else:
            return ("Code = {}, {}, ${:.2f}, quantity = {}".format(self.code, self.description, self.price, self.quantity))
        
    def __repr__(self):
        return ("ShoppingItem({}, '{}', {}, {})".format(self.code,self.description, self.price, self.quantity ))
        
    def set_price(self, new_price):
        if new_price > 0:
            self.price = new_price
```

Now I am required to define another class `Shopping`. I need to implement the `load_data(self)` method which should invoke the `read_file()` method to get a list of strings, convert the list of strings into a list of `ShoppingItem` objects and assign the list into the `self.items_list` variable. The `read_file()` method reads in the contents from the `self.filename` file. If the file cannot be read properly, then the `self.items_list` remains unchanged (i.e. an empty list).

```
class Shopping:
    def __init__(self, filename = 'stocks.txt'):
        self.filename = filename
        Shopping.items_list = []
        
    def read_file(self):
        try:
            input_file = open(self.filename, 'r')
            contents = input_file.read()
            content_list = contents.split('\n')
            
        except FileNotFoundError:
            print ("ERROR: The file '{}' does not exist.".format(self.filename))
            
        else:
            input_file.close()
            return content_list
    
    def load_data(self):
        self.items_list = ShoppingItem(self.read_file())
            #here is where I am having problem writing the code. Can someone guide me to complete this
```

Can someone please tell me how I can achieve what is in the expected output. How do I convert the list of strings into a list of `ShoppingItem` objects

Test:

```
shop = Shopping('stocks.txt')
shop.load_data()
print(len(shop.items_list))
print(type(shop.items_list[0]))
print(type(shop.items_list[0].code))
print(type(shop.items_list[0].description))
print(type(shop.items_list[0].price))
print(type(shop.items_list[0].quantity))
```

Expected Output:

```
10
<class '__main__.ShoppingItem'>
<class 'int'>
<class 'str'>
<class 'float'>
<class 'int'>
```

Output Received:

```
***Error***
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "__tester__.python3", line 66, in <module>
    shop.load_data()
  File "__tester__.python3", line 33, in load_data
    self.items_list = ShoppingItem(self.read_file())
TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'description'
```

**SAMPLE TEXT FILE CONTENTS:

```
11,Coca Cola Soft Drink 500ml,4,2
12,L & P Soft Drink Lemon & Paeroa 500ml,4,9
13,V Blue Drink can 500mL,3.5,8
14,V Vitalise Energy Drink 500ml,3.5,5
15,Pump Water NZ Spring 750ml,2.5,9
16,Twix Chocolate Bar 50g,2.5,12
17,Nestle Kit Kat Chocolate Bar 4 Finger, 2.4,15
18,Snickers Chocolate Bar 50g,2,11
19,Cadbury Chocolate Bar Crunchie 50g, 2,13
20,Cadbury Picnic Chocolate Bar 46g,2,15
```

Comment: That looks like CSV contents. I'd suggest looking into `csv` module.

Comment: Do you want to parse it as CSV or as a string? there are libraries for CSV which might be helpful, but of course one can always go through the text with for example a `for`-loop and `split(",")`.

Comment: as a string, we're not allowed to use CSV libraries.  What I'm confused about is How do I convert the list of strings into a list of `ShoppingItem` objects

Comment: Which object do you  want  `items_list` be an attrib of ? Where is a value assigned to ir ?

Comment: Is it mandatory for `Shopping` to have a public method `read_file`? If not either change the name to `_read_file` or put it in the `load_data` method

Comment: @yowhatsup123 I just formatted the file contents to display a little better. can you confirm if there are blank newlines between lines with the text in the orginal text file? Because I think I stripped those out when formatting it.

Comment: @hpchavaz the assignment clearly mentions that they should be different methods and it has to have a public method because that's what is accepted

Comment: @rv.kvetch The contents of the file seem to be the same. They are separated by a new line character

Comment: @yowhatsup123: `'error.txt'` not existing is completely different from the problem you initially described. You can't change the question so completely after it's been answered. The missing file is because `error.txt` is not in your working directory; make sure you are *in* the same directory as `error.txt` when you run the script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `list_of_str` will contain all the data in a [comma-separated-value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values) format, and the data of each item will be separated by a new line.

You can loop through each item in the `list_of_str` then extract the values using `.split(',')` method. This will give you `code, desc, price, quant` (in this particular sequence)

Then you need to push the object of `ShoppingItem` in the `item_list` for a particular item. You can do so by creating a new object `ShoppingItem(code=code, description=desc, price=price, quantity=quant)` and then appending it to the `item_list`.

so the code will look like this:

```
def load_data(self):
    list_of_strs = self.read_file()
    for item in list_of_strs:
        code, desc, price, quant = item.split(',')
        self.items_list.append(ShoppingItem(code=code, description=desc, price=price, quantity=quant))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a csv.DictReader to get the contents of the file.
https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html

Change the read_file method to something like

```
with open(self.filename, 'r') as input_file:
    reader = csv.DictReader(input_file)
    for row in reader:
        self.items_list.append(ShoppingItem(**row))
```

assuming the args on ShoppingItem equal the header row of the csv file otherwise you will need to tweak a bit

Comment: Unfortunately, they do not accept an answer which is not covered in syllabus yet so I will not receive marks for this. I need to do it the way mentioned in the code above.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I'd suggest abstracting the loading of the `ShoppingItem` objects as a class method in the `ShoppingItem` class itself. This is a bit easier as you don't need to define another class which returns a list of `ShoppingItem` objects.

I'd also suggest looking into [dataclasses](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html), which I personally like for this use case, as it provides a nice layer of abstraction around Python classes, which also helps to  improve on code quality a little.

For the `price` field, I'd also suggest using *properties* in Python, as the nice thing is that the setter method is invoked whenever you use the `obj.price = x` syntax, for example.

I feel like these changes actually aligns well with the ["Zen of Python"](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/):

> Simple is better than complex.

```py
# needed to support `str | int` syntax in Python 3.7+
from __future__ import annotations

from dataclasses import dataclass, field
from pathlib import Path
from pprint import pprint


@dataclass
class ShoppingItem:
    code: int
    description: str
    price: float = 1.0
    quantity: int = 1

    # needed for better IDE support
    _price: float = field(init=False, repr=False)

    def __post_init__(self):
        self.code = int(self.code)
        self.description = str(self.description)
        self.price = self.price
        self.quantity = int(self.quantity)

    def __str__(self):
        if not self.quantity:
            return "Code = {}, {} - Out of Stock".format(self.code, self.description)
        return (
            "Code = {}, {}, ${:.2f}, quantity = {}".format(self.code, self.description, self.price, self.quantity))

    # noinspection PyRedeclaration
    @property
    def price(self) -> float:
        return self._price

    @price.setter
    def price(self, new_price: str | float):
        new_price = float(new_price)
        if new_price > 0:
            self._price = new_price

    @classmethod
    def from_file(cls, filename: str) -> list[ShoppingItem]:
        """Create list of ShoppingItems from a comma-separated file."""
        lines = Path(filename).read_text().splitlines()
        shopping_items = [cls(*line.split(',')) for line in lines]

        return shopping_items


my_items = ShoppingItem.from_file('my_file.txt')

print('Count of Shopping Items:', len(my_items))
pprint(my_items)
```

With recent changes and much needed improvements to the builtin `pprint` module added in Python 3.10, it now correctly pretty-prints *dataclass* instances as desired:

```
Count of Shopping Items: 10
[ShoppingItem(code=11,
              description='Coca Cola Soft Drink 500ml',
              price=4.0,
              quantity=2),
 ShoppingItem(code=12,
              description='L & P Soft Drink Lemon & Paeroa 500ml',
              price=4.0,
              quantity=9),
...]
```